# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'booked' (T_STRING) in eval()'d code

Tags: php, debugging, eval

I am receiving the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'booked' (T_STRING) in eval()'d code.

Here is my code:

```
    $cvalue = do_shortcode( $cvalue );

    eval( '$cvalue="\n<div class=\"advcustomvalue\">\n' . $cvalue . '\n</div>\n";' );

    echo urldecode( stripslashes( $cvalue ) );

    if ( $posttext ) {
    echo $posttext;
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this syntax error in the eval code (line 3)?

Thanks,

Jonathan

Comment: Depends on what `$cvalue` is doesn't it?

Comment: This piece of code is very vulnerable to injections, which is exactly what has happened. `$cvalue` contains a quote, leaving the code that you're `eval`'ing with a syntax error. Did you ever hear that `eval` is evil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use eval, like NEVER, especially not if you want to do a trivial thing as concatenating strings.

Just do this:

```
$cvalue = sprintf("\n<div class=\"advcustomvalue\">\n%s\n</div>\n", $cvalue);
```